# pivoting a single row dataframe where groupBy can not be applied

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe like this:

| inputRecordSetCount | inputRecordCount | suspenseRecordCount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 166 | 1216 | 10 |

I am trying to make it look like

| operation | value |
| --- | --- |
| inputRecordSetCount | 166 |
| inputRecordCount | 1216 |
| suspenseRecordCount | 10 |

I tried `pivot`, but it needs a `groupBy` field. I dont have any `groupBy` field. I found some reference of `Stack` in Scala. But not sure, how to use it in PySpark. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `stack()` operation as mentioned in [this tutorial](https://www.hadoopinrealworld.com/understanding-stack-function-in-spark/).

Since there are 3 unique values, pass the size, and pair of label and column name:

```py
stack(3, "inputRecordSetCount", inputRecordSetCount, "inputRecordCount", inputRecordCount, "suspenseRecordCount", suspenseRecordCount) as (operation, value)
```

Full example:

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=[[166,1216,10]], schema=['inputRecordSetCount','inputRecordCount','suspenseRecordCount'])

cols = [f'"{c}", {c}' for c in df.columns]
exprs = f"stack({len(cols)}, {', '.join(str(c) for c in cols)}) as (operation, value)"
df = df.selectExpr(exprs)

df.show()

+-------------------+-----+
|          operation|value|
+-------------------+-----+
|inputRecordSetCount|  166|
|   inputRecordCount| 1216|
|suspenseRecordCount|   10|
+-------------------+-----+
```

Comment: Thank you for providing the tutorial link and providing the solution.