# transition matrix from pyspark dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, matrix, pyspark, group-by, spark-window-function

I have two columns (such as):

| from | to |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 4 | 3 |
| 3 | 3 |

And I want to create a transition matrix (where sum of rows in a columns add up to 1):

```py
         1.      2.     3.   4.

1.      0        0      0    0
2.      0.5*     0      0    2/3
3.      0.5      0.5    1    1/3
4.      0        0.5    0    0
```

where 1 -> 2 would be :  (the number of times 1 (in 'from') is next to 2 (in 'to)) / (total times 1 points to any value).

Comment: Your sample expected output does not match with the transformation requested. Please provide correct sample input/expected output.

Comment: @AzharKhan yes I updated the question. Let me know if it is more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create this kind of transition matrix using a window and pivot.

First some dummy data:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(42)
x = np.random.randint(1,5,100)
y = np.random.randint(1,5,100)

df = spark.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame({'from': x, 'to': y}))
df.show()
```

```
+----+---+
|from| to|
+----+---+
|   3|  3|
|   4|  2|
|   1|  2|
...
```

To create a pct column, first group the data by unique combinations of from/to and get the counts. With that aggregated dataframe, create a new column, `pct` that uses the `Window` to find the total number of records for each `from` group which is used as the denominator.

Lastly, pivot the table to make the `to` values columns and the `pct` data the values of the matrix.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

w = Window().partitionBy('from')
grp = df.groupBy('from', 'to').count().withColumn('pct', F.col('count') / F.sum('count').over(w))

res = grp.groupBy('from').pivot('to').agg(F.round(F.first('pct'), 2))
res.show()
```

```
+----+----+----+----+----+
|from|   1|   2|   3|   4|
+----+----+----+----+----+
|   1| 0.2| 0.2|0.25|0.35|
|   2|0.27|0.31|0.19|0.23|
|   3|0.46|0.17|0.21|0.17|
|   4|0.13|0.13| 0.5|0.23|
+----+----+----+----+----+
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help @Zelazny7! This works! But I actually need the sum of the columns to be equal to 1 and not the sum of the rows. I also change the order of to and from such as below

Comment: w = Window().partitionBy('to')
grp = data.groupBy('to', 'from').count().withColumn('pct', F.col('count') / F.sum('count').over(w))

res = grp.groupBy('to').pivot('from').agg(F.round(F.first('pct'), 2))
res.show()

Comment: @lac, I had the same understanding as zelazny7 when you said you need sum of columns. But it looks like what you are looking for is: for a given column, sum of its all rows. Well in that case, just transpose the matrix. This, being a summary table, should work with "toPandas().T" or if you want Spark way then check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74574775/pivoting-a-single-row-dataframe-where-groupby-can-not-be-applied/74579589#74579589.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help. I want to do it in spark and looks like it is not that easy if you have that many rows/columns. @AzharKhan any chance we can sum the rows given one column?